# Windows 7 VM on Raspberry Pi 400

Tags: virtualbox, windows-7, raspberrypi

So finally, I got the Raspberry Pi 400. I installed MATE and VirtualBox on it, and I am wondering how Windows 7 would go. I accolated it 1024MB of RAM and gave it 32GB of storage. I have a 256GB MicroSD card with it.

Would Windows 7 run well on a Pi 400, knowing there is 4GB of RAM? I haven't installed it yet.

Comment: Does Windows 7 run on ARM processors? I don't know. Where do you get the installation ISO for Windows 7 binary for ARM?

Comment: I dumped it myself from an old win7 PC before it broke

Comment: It won't work. Your old PC had Intel (or AMD) CPU. The Pi 400 has ARM CPU. Putting Windows on Pi is like putting diesel in the tank of gasoline car. It won't work.

Comment: Even through VirtualBox??